# Read XML elements from a specific node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing

Here the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MyResponse xmlns="http://mynamespace">
    <Header>
        <FirstName>David</FirstName>
        <LastName>Duchovny</LastName>
    </Header>
    <Filmography>
        <Films>     
        </Films>
        <Series>
            <Serie>
                <Title>X-Files</Title>
                <Year>1989</Year>
            </Serie>
        </Series>

    </Filmography>  
</MyResponse>
```

I'd like only get the `Header` section to this object :

```
public class Header
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I did this (we can't use deserialization) :

```
const string nameSapce = "http://mynamespace">
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\csv.xml");
var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("myApplication", nameSapce);
XmlNode node = xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//myApplication:MyResponse", namespaceManager);
Console.WriteLine(node);
```

I get this as result in the `node` variable :

```
<Header xmlns="http://mynamespace">
    <FirstName>David</FirstName>
    <LastName>Duchovny</LastName>
</Header>
```

How can I extract the `Header` item to the `Header` object ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **LINQ to XML**, you can use it with the select the **Header** class from the xml Object,

Exemples:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview